# Add .htaccess to cache manifest?

Tags: .htaccess, cache-manifest

Do I need to add my .htaccess file to my cache manifest?

I know that all the files required for a site need to be added for it to work offline, but is the .htaccess part of the site in the same sense? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This file is part of the server config, and should be set to be inaccessible to the user.